# MATLAB: use the maple() command?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, maple

I have Maple installed on my system and I would like to do all my symbolic computations from within MATLAB by calling maple through the Maple's [MATLAB Connectivity](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/features/matlabconnectivity.aspx) feature.

I have found out that there exists a command `maple('')` inside MATLAB which allows to execute Maple commands from inside MATLAB, but I am confused about how to use it! Here is an example problem that I'm having:

```
>> syms x y z a b c;
>> vec=maple('<x,y,z>');
>> vec2=maple('<a,b,c>');
>> maple('CrossProduct(vec,vec2)')

ans =

                            CrossProduct(vec, vec2)
```

You see that Maple does not use the variables `vec` and `vec2` that I just defined... how do I make Maple use them? Thank you!

Comment: try `maple('CrossProduct','vec',vec2')`. I think its the solution but dont have Maple at the moment. Also, Matlab has a "Maple sytntax" module, called MuPad

Comment: `>> maple('CrossProduct','vec',vec2')
 
ans =
 
                CrossProduct(vec, [conj(a), conj(b), conj(c)])` it seems to not work.

Comment: Did you intend to call `LinearAlgebra:-CrossProduct` instead of just `CrossProduct` (which means nothing special in Maple unless you've rebound that by loading the package via `with(LinearAlgebra)`.